Can Hoare's partition method be used for partitioning around a specific pivot?
Studying quicksort , I discovered some weird behaviours of the partitioning algorithm (taught by our instructor) when testing it out for random pivots . After quite some research, I found out I was taught a modification of Hoare's partition algorithm where you would take the pivot as the first element and then swap it with the value of the right pointer(jth position) in the end. The general Hoare's algorithm however, behaves in a stranger manner .
First I discovered that it might not be necessary for it to partition around the selected pivot but do it around a completely different one . For e.g. consider the array  {2,1,4,6,9,5,3,7} . If 6 is the pivot , the algorithm ends up partitioning around 5 instead : {2,1,4,3,5,9,6,7} and then we cannot return a single pivot value from the function but make the following calls from the same function:
Quicksort(a,lo,j) ;  Quicksort(a,i,hi) ;  which means we include the pivot as well in the next call .
This is the code I found working for random pivots from @rcgldr:
void QuickSort(int *a, int low, int high)
{
    int i, j;
    int p, t;
    if(low >= high)
        return;
    p = a[(low+high)/2] ;
    i = low;
    j = high;
    while (i <= j){
        while (a[i] < p )i++;
        while (a[j] > p )j--;
            if (i > j)
                break;
            t = a[i];
            a[i] = a[j];
            a[j] = t;
            i++;
            j--;
    }
    QuickSort(a, low, j);
    QuickSort(a, i, high);
}

Is there any way I could modify the above code so that it partitions the array around the index of the pivot and not include the pivot in the succeeding calls** .In general, it seems to be around the jth element but when the pivot is the largest element , it would be around the ith element(for e.g. in the array {80,73,48,90,33,53,60} if 90 is the pivot, i points to 90 in the end). This is all because I want to implement an iterative version of quicksort as well with this scheme of partitioning, where you would have to store the pivots in a stack . We could grab a random pivot and swap it with the 1st element like my instructor said, but doing that seems more like dodging the issue.
Moreover, I couldn't really get an intuition about how Hoare's algorithm partitions the array . The cases where it partitions the array in a completely unpredicted manner are what throw me off ( say if we modify the previous array: {53,80,73,48,90,33,60,110,70}, then it doesn't even partition around any pivot). I would greatly benefit if some insight is thrown on this as well .

@500-InternalServerError I think that's wrong , if you check what I have written in my post as well : "If 6 is the pivot , the algorithm ends up partitioning around 5 instead : {2,1,4,3,5,9,6,7}"  , 9 is to the left of 6 here , that's with the code I have referenced .

The two partitions in that should be 2,1,4,3,5 and 9,6,7. The pivot value can be moved during the partition.

Upon looking again, I think you are correct, actually: there appears to be a bug in that algo. @Shawn: the position of the pivot value can change, but not the value itself, and i and j should be the end and beginning of the partitions, respectively, before the recursive call, but they're not. Instead they're 5 and 4, respectively (i.e. they overlap).

You write: "I was taught a modification of Hoare's partition algorithm where you would take the pivot as the first element and then swap it with the value of the right pointer(jth position) in the end.". I am confused. It seems like you already have the answer to your question.

"...but doing that seems more like dodging the issue.": yes, Hoare's partitioning scheme  is intended to not worry about the final placement of the pivot. If you force it to do it in a way that the pivot sits between the two resulting partitions, you'll need extra swaps which will lead to a total number of swaps that is greater than before. If you want a result where the two partitions are separated by an element (that has the pivot value), then go for Lomuto's partitioning scheme, but realise that Hoare's scheme sorts with fewer swaps on average.

"I would greatly benefit if some insight is thrown on this as well": this makes your question too broad. Can you focus your question more to one issue?

@MkB, Minor: (low+high)/2 may overflow.  low + (high-low)/2 does not. (when high > low >= 0.)

@trincot I was just wondering how the algorithm logically ensures partitioning when the very element it partitions around can end up being just another element in one of the partitions . What I mean is, if you look at the end result , there is no way of verifying that the array was partitioned around 6 , it could have been any other element as well like 9 or 7 . That is the thing that seems counter-intuitive .

I don't know what you mean with 'around' in this context. 5 does not play a special role.

There is no need to find back what the pivot value was. All that is needed are two partitions where the left one has no value that is greater than any value in the right partition.

The primary advantage of Hoare partition scheme is that it doesn't need to do a check to see if either index has reached the start or end of the current partition. In the inner while loops, only one if statement is used, element < pivot value or element > pivot value. This requires that the pivot or an element equal to the pivot be swapped so that the next iteration of while loops will get stopped by the pivot if needed. The result of this is elements equal to the pivot or the pivot itself can end up anywhere in the current partition and can't be excluded. The end result of a partition step is the left part has elements <= pivot value and the right part has elements >= pivot value. Elements == pivot value can end up in either part.
The code in the question is a post-increment | post-decrement variation of Hoare partition scheme. There is a tiny chance that an element equal to the pivot or the pivot itself is excluded in the special case where i == j+2 when the outer loop terminates (such as a reverse sorted array).
The following code is a classic pre-increment | pre-decrment version of Hoare partition scheme. This variation never excludes any element.
void QuickSort(int a[], int lo, int hi)
{
    if(lo >= hi)
        return;
    int p = a[lo+(hi-lo)/2];
    int i = lo-1;
    int j = hi+1;
    while(1){
        while (a[++i] < p);
        while (a[--j] > p);
        if(i >= j)
            break;
        int t = a[i];
        a[i] = a[j];
        a[j] = t;
    }
    i = j++;
    QuickSort(a, lo, i);
    QuickSort(a, j, hi);
}

The original implementation of quicksort was done on system that didn't have a stack, so it was an iterative version that used a program created stack which Hoare called a nest at the time. To limit stack space to O(log2(n)), only the indexes for the larger part of a partition split are pushed onto the stack, and the smaller part is handled by looping back with an updated value for lo or hi. For recursive quicksort like the code used here, the code would recurse on the smaller part, and iterate on the larger part. The common logic for both implementations is to handle the smaller part first and handle the larger part later. Worst case time complexity remains O(n^2).
